# How to get Statement Context nodes from antlr4ts parse tree

Tags: angular, typescript, antlr

I have a parse tree generated using antlr4ts I want to extract the statement context nodes from it.
My generated parse tree nodes look like below

```
TerminalNode {_symbol: CommonToken, _parent: UnitContext}
TerminalNode {_symbol: CommonToken, _parent: UnitContext}
StatementContext {_parent: UnitContext, invokingState: 178, _start: CommonToken, children: Array(1), _stop: CommonToken}children: [AssignmentContext]invokingState: 178_parent: UnitContext {_parent: ProgramContext, invokingState: 186, _start: CommonToken, children: Array(7), _stop: CommonToken}_start: CommonToken {_line: 3, _charPositionInLine: 4, _channel: 0, index: 2, _text: undefined, …}_stop: CommonToken {_line: 3, _charPositionInLine: 11, _channel: 0, index: 4, _text: undefined, …}altNumber: (...)childCount: (...)isEmpty: (...)parent: (...)payload: (...)ruleContext: (...)ruleIndex: (...)sourceInterval: (...)start: (...)stop: (...)text: (...)[[Prototype]]: ParserRuleContext
StatementContext {_parent: UnitContext, invokingState: 178, _start: CommonToken, children: Array(1), _stop: CommonToken}
StatementContext {_parent: UnitContext, invokingState: 178, _start: CommonToken, children: Array(1), _stop: CommonToken}
StatementContext {_parent: UnitContext, invokingState: 178, _start: CommonToken, children: Array(1), _stop: CommonToken}
TerminalNode {_symbol: CommonToken, _parent: UnitContext}
```

could anyone please tell me how can I extract the statement context nodes from it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "extract" you mean you want to find all `StatementContext` nodes in the parser tree, correct?

A typical approach is to create an own listener to walk over the parse tree and only handle the statement rule:

```
export class YourParseTreeWalker implements YourParserListener {
    public exitStatement = (ctx: StatementContext): void => {
        // Do your processing here.
    };
}
```

You would run the walk by calling:

```
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new YourParseTreeWalker());
```

Comment: Hi @Mike Lischke thanks for the help could you please also tell me how can I print the parse tree in representational Format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=antlr4+print+tree

Comment: Hi @Mike Lischke I went through the above link but didn't understand much.  let me give you some more background my backend team has generated parser,lexer etc for typescript we are using them in our angular applications I am able to generate a parse and print that tree to console but I am struggling in printing  its visual representation . I am using Vscode as my code editor

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Open new questions, if you need more information.

Comment: Sure will open a new question Mike Lischke